# Google nearbyplaces is returning 23 places but the map is only displaying 12

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-places-api, google-places

I am calling out to google places and am getting back the correct places but when i go to display them on the map, only a half of the returned places are being displayed. I know there is a limit of 20 places per "screen" that google allows but why is it not hitting at least 20 places?

```
const urlCafe =
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" +
  latitude +
  "," +
  longitude +
  "&radius=" +
  radMetter +
  "&type=" +
  cafeKeyword +
  "&keyword=" +
  coffeeKeyword +
  "&key=" +
  config.API_KEY;

let cafePlaces = await fetch(urlCafe)
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(res => {
    for (let googlePlace of res.results) {
      if (
        googlePlace &&
        googlePlace.opening_hours &&
        googlePlace.business_status &&
        googlePlace.business_status != "CLOSED_TEMPORARILY"
      ) {
        let place = {};
        let lat = googlePlace.geometry.location.lat;
        let lng = googlePlace.geometry.location.lng;
        let coordinate = {
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: lng,
        };

        place["placeType"] = "cafe";
        place["vicinity"] = googlePlace.vicinity;
        place["open"] = googlePlace.opening_hours.open_now;
        place["placeTypes"] = googlePlace.types;
        place["rating"] = googlePlace.rating;
        place["coordinate"] = coordinate;
        place["placeId"] = googlePlace.place_id;
        place["user_ratings_total"] = googlePlace.user_ratings_total;
        place["placeName"] = googlePlace.name;
        placesArray.push(place);
      }
    }
    return placesArray;
  });



      <MapView
          ref={mapRef}
          onMapReady={() => {
            if (mapRef.current) {
              mapRef.current.fitToCoordinates(
                placesArray.map(location => location.coordinate),
                {
                  edgePadding: {
                    top: 10,
                    right: 10,
                    bottom: 10,
                    left: 10,
                  },
                  animated: true,
                }
              );
            }
          }}
          style={styles.map}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          onRegionChange={e => onRegionChange(e)}
        >
          {placesArray && placesArray.length > 0
            ? placesArray.map((marker, key) => {
                if (marker == undefined) return null;
                return (
                  <Marker
                    coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                    title={marker.placeName}
                    key={key}
                    ....
```